Shrinking edges without breaking geometry/intersecting with inteself
I am trying to "bevel" the top of the hole of an object inwards, tried a few ways to do it, but I am always facing some issue and the final result is not perfect.
So, I have a non-symmetrical object with a hole going through it. It is a faily high-poly model. Lets take this shape for an example:

The final result that I want to archieve looks something like this:

The result on the above photo is done by selecting the inner edge loop and scaling it down.
But there is an issue - the scaling of the hole is not the same all around. This can be seen with a view from the top:

The scaling is just not uniform - and I want all sides to have the same sized "ramp" going inside the model, even if the model is not symmetrical.
Now, I can use the shrink/fatten funtion, instead of the scaling:

However with such high poly count the geometry starts to self-intersect and is basically creating a mess where all the edges and faces intersect in the inner corners of the hole.
Bottom line:
Scaling works fine as it does not break the geometry of the model, but is not uniform.
Shrink usually does the stuff more uniformly, but constantly breaks the geometry on tight corners with high poly count.
There must be a way to achieve what I am trying, but I can't get to it. The models I am working on have more complex shapes and the problem is even more pronounced.
Edits after receiving some comments:

The mesh in the example is just a simple, high poly mesh to illustrate the issue. The real models I am working on are more complex in their shapes and the problem is even more pronounced. However, the issue is still perfectly visible in the example mesh provided and easier to reproduce and discuss.
All scales are applied, so X-Y-Z scales are all 1-1-1.

Wanted to post an animated comment to Martynas's answer, but since gif can't be inside comments, I will post it as an answer.
Tried your idea with the outset function, but I am encountering geometry problems, most probably due to the higher poly count compared to your example:

Afterwards the bevel as expected is not behaving properly as well.

Hello and welcome to BSE. Why do you need such a dense mesh? I don't think it's necessary. Also it's very difficult to work with dense meshes. Since it's a simple shape I would recommend redoing the model from scratch with less geometry and then continue experimenting.

Hi there! The shape in the post is just an example mesh to illustrate the issue that I am having.

Can you check the scale of the object in Object Mode, is it (1,1,1)?

ALT + S..... :)

@MarkusvonBroady Alt-S clears the scale. Ctrl-S > Scale apples it which is what is needed here!

Ah, I misread as I usually do, it's just a topology problem (skill issue :D)

Yes, forgot to mention that this is not a problem related to scaling in object mode and forgetting to apply it. All scales are 1-1-1.

You should show a real problematic model. I could give a solution for this case, but then how do I know I am not wasting my time because the actual models are different and it will not work?..

@MartynasŽiemys reproducing an issue in a simple case is something we generally approve or even suggest, and if you answer the question is not too localized, then answering it is still a value added even if it doesn't satisfy the OP's original problem.

I was not thinking straight yesterday. You can simply disable Loop Slide for bevels to make them more uniform. At the moment the example model simply has unneeded topology that can be deleted to solve any issues. I assume this might not be the case with actual models.
